# SAT Geometry Reflection problem

Tags: geometry

Number 57: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J7a8.jpg

Answer D:
I drew what I believe should be where the square are located. If my drawing is correct, not sure how the new A' coordinates are now -d, -c

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reflection maps $(1,0)$ to $(0,-1)$.

The reflection also maps $(0,1)$ to $(-1,0)$.

Hence to compute the image of $(c,d)$, we just have to compute

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} c \\ d\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} -d \\ -c \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

An answer that doesn't use matrices.

Draw the rectangle $OIAJ$ where $O = (0,0)$, $I = (c,0)$, $J = (0,d)$, $A = (c,d)$.

Now reflect the rectangle $OIAJ$ through $y = -x$ to get a rectangle $O'I'A'J'$. We have $O' = O$, $I' = (0,-c)$, $J' = (-d,0)$. Therefore we must have $A' = (-d,-c)$.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be solved by analytical method (but is a bit tedious).

We know that A’, the reflected image of A about L : y = –x, will lie on L’ : y = x + p (for some constant p) because $L \bot L’$.

Since A(c, d) lies also on L’, we have d = c + p (or p = d – c). Then, we get L’ : y = x + {d – c}……(1)

A and A’ are the points of intersection of L’ and the circle $K : x^2 + y^2 = c^2 + d^2$.

Solving L’ and K, we get …….. $x^2 + (d – c) x – dc = 0$......(2)

We know c is one of the root of (2) and the other root (which should be the x- coordinate of A’) must be –d by applying the product of roots.

Finally, from (1), we get $A’ = (- d, - c)$.